# How to ground wi-fi antenna outer wire on circuit board connector?

Tags: antenna

[image]I have a quick question regarding a Wi-Fi antenna modification I am doing to my drone controller. I want to replace the antenna which is soldered to the board in the controller. I want to replace it with a SMA connector, so that I may mount an external antenna instead.

My question is: how do I ground the outer wire on the circuit board? Is it okay to run a wire carrying the outer wire current to GND? Or do I have to use the antenne ground? Where would I find that? [image]

Comment: Is that a feedthru cap to antenna with gnd on either side and trace under it?

Comment: That's just it, I'm not sure if it might be so. I've seen another guy do the same mod on YouTube, and it looks like he just removed some insulation from the board next to the antenna and soldered the shield on the copper plate there. That would indicate you are correct, right? Although I'm not sure he did it right at all, which is why I'm looking into it.. and based on the other comments here, he did most certainly not..

Comment: I don't see any testing done for ground plane continuity , what I said is not contradicted by any evidence.

Comment: i didnt mean that you were saying anything wrong, but i was asking if what that guy on youtube had done made any sense then..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no proper wiring of the return path on that board. If you connected the shield of your external antenna "somewhere" to GND, you won't get an external antenna but just a long internal+external antenna wire.

Find the WiFi PHY chip (could be that one near to the existing antenna) and check which pin is HF ground. Your cable shield goes there.

EDIT: Oh yes, and Marcus is right, wire antennas are often enough **not** 50Ω impedance so you may need an impedance matching transformer.

Comment: I think i found a schematic of the chip, it was the one next to the antenna it seems, but still cant idetify HF ground? any ideas? (I added the schematic above)..

Comment: A typical application on page 9ff: https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwij7aXFwdPZAhVBKuwKHREoA-QQFgg4MAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rfmw.com%2Fdata%2FRFaxis-Freescale_ZigBee_Range_Extension_with_RFX2401_AppNote.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3bu-eGdDomXgkgoedpqN8k And no, no explicit HF ground. Pick any GND pin of that chip connected through a low impedance path.

Comment: https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/472/rfaxis_RFX2401C%20Data%20Sheet%20R4-1213860.pdf

Comment: okay, so i think ive got it then, now i only need to find the best possible way to solder something on that tiny chip! =D by the way, as far as I can see from the datasheet, the the impedance of this wire antenna is 50 ohms, so i dont need a matching transformer??

Comment: The chip at least is built for 50Ω impedance, so you could expect the board you have can go with this. That simple wire antenna it has at the moment most likely doesn't have 50Ω. About the soldering: Solder it to the board, as near to the GND pins as possible.

Answer (score 0):

That just looks like a wire antenna – a monopole.

If you want to connect an actual transmission line to the transmitter, you'll have to figure out what that IC is, and which pins are meant to transport RF.

Then you need to guesstimate (you won't be able to measure) the impedance of that line – you really won't gain much by connecting an external antenna whose impedance isn't well-matched to your circuitry. You get a better antenna at the expense of having much higher losses.

All in all: you can try to solder the outer conductor *somewhere* to ground, but chances are you're not getting a better system than before, but worse.